# System calls involved in writing a blocks to datanodes in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, operating-system, filesystems, hdfs, distributed-filesystem

As per my understanding of HDFS, HDFS is a higher level file system that abstracts the local file system with a huge block size (64 MB). When the client wants to write a file to HDFS, depending on the replication factor a pipeline will be formed.

Then HDFSClient will cache the file up to the block size (e.g. 64 MB) and streams the data in terms of 4 KB packets to the first DataNode in the pipeline followed by remaining data nodes. Since these blocks are normal files to the local file system on which HDFS is running.

I would like to know:

1. How these packets of 4 KB are written to the local file system of DataNode?
2. What are the system calls made by the DataNode demons to write it on Hard disks?